# Задана на python. Мишка Лимак

Tags: python

Суть задачи вы ведите в скрине:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой код начинает некорректно работать во-втором примере. Т.к во втором примере Лимак, Что боб в установленный момент начинают весить одинаково, а в моём коде, пока a <b, переменная a как не странно уже не больше, а ровна b.

```
a, b = map(int, input().split())
year = 0  
while b > a:
    year += 1
    a = a * 3
    b = b * 2
 print(year)
```

Что делать?

Comment: Приведите задание в текстовом виде

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Больше или равно:

```
while b >= a:
```

```js
function countYears(a, b) {
  var year = 0
  while (b >= a) {
    year += 1;
    a = a * 3;
    b = b * 2;
  }
  return year;
}

console.log(countYears(4, 7));
console.log(countYears(4, 9));
console.log(countYears(1, 1));
```

Comment: Может я не очень правильно описал ситуации или вы её не так поняли. Суть в том чтобы a было как больше или Не равно b

Comment: @Valerka288, что, простите? "Больше или не равно"??? Во-первых, если больше, то это уже не равно. Во-вторых, если нужно учесть ещё и случаи, где меньше, используйте просто "не равно".